# Allow users to change keyboard keys of application

Tags: java, keyboard

I don't know what is wrong with what I have been searching, but I have to imagine I am searching wrong.  Are there any examples of ways people have done the following:

On an options screen, allowed user to change what keys do what in their application:

-i.e. Change up arrow to W key, or change down arrow to S key. WASD vs ULDR.

I am not being lazy, per say, I just have seen so many games that have this setup and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Can anyone give me an example of how to do this or link me please?  Thanks so much.

Comment: For which application you want to change the keys?

Comment: I have a game, and I want to allow my users to pick which key is 'move up' in game.  Maybe that makes more sense, its not so much to change keyboard functionality as it is to change which keys do what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here for java callback reference http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip10.html

The idea is that you create a dictionary of keys and callbacks like the ones described in the previous site (dictionary reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html).

The callbacks with only one method declared:

```
public interface MovementCallbackInterface {

    public void method();
}
```

Then create classes such as:

```
public class MoveForward implements MovementCallbackInterface {

    public void method() {
        //Move forward code
    }
```

And then you create the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<KeyEvent, MovementCallbackInterface> d;
```

At runtime for each key you assign a callback like

```
MoveForward mf = new MoveForward();
d.put(KeyEvent.VK_W, mf);
```

When you want to switch keys you can just modify the key assignment in the dictionary to point to your new callback.

```
d.remove(KeyEvent.VK_W);
d.put(KeyEvent.VK_U, mf);
```

Then every time a key is pressed you search for that key in the dictionary and call the method of the MovementCallbackInterface object, like

```
d.get(KeyEvent.VK_W).method().
```

Maybe there's a fastest way, in c++ you can use function pointer for example, or delegates in c#, which contains only functions and not entire classes. Anyway this method works in java.